# Specifying from the general in probability: Does it work?

Tags: probability, terminology

If the average classroom AC holds 30 students, and 1 in 10 students throughout the US has a probability of having condition A, does that mean there's a 300% chance there's a student in classroom AC that holds condition A?

Comment: What does a 300% chance that anything happens, even mean?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote and the votes to close.  The question is very clear to me.  Although "300% chance" is nonsense to those of us who already "get it," please let none of us forget that many people who ask questions here don't have that same level of knowledge and are just trying to understand.

Comment: @tilper Completely XY. The issue is whether there's a 100% chance there's a student in AC with A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. By definition probabilities can only be in $[0,1]$ or from $0\%$ to $100\%$. "$300\%$ chance" is meaningless. A better way to do the calculation is to consider the proportion of students who have the condition as a probability: $$\Pr(\text{a student has condition }A)=\frac{1}{10}$$ So the chance that there is at least one student in a 30 person classroom with condition $A$ is $$\begin{align}1-\Pr(\text{no student has condition }A) &= 1- \Pr(\text{a student does not have }A)^{30} \\&= 1- \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{30} \\&\approx 96\%\end{align}$$

Assuming the probabilities are independent.

Comment: Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: @JossieCalderon A basic probability/statistics textbook or course will teach you how to solve this sort of problem.

Comment: What sort of problem is this?

Comment: well??????????????

Comment: I'd just call it a probability problem.

Comment: Considering that's too broad, that does not qualify as an answer.

Comment: That's fair. It's a probability calculation of an outcome of a Bernoulli process. In particular the number of students with the condition has a binomial distribution. If you check out [this calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=probability+binomial) and enter 30 trials, probability = 1/10, and endpoint = 0 you can see the probability that >0 students have the condition. The reason I gave such a broad answer before is there are many other probability distributions which are appropriate to use in other (similar) problems. Does that help?